# How to use GMP library in dev c with gcc4.7.2

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gmp, gcc4.7

I have absolutely no idea about using gmp. Need some functions for a project and need a quick installation guide. I am Absolutely beginner to this field so please help accordingly.

I have:

- Dev C++ 5.4.2 in windows 8.1 configuration with GCC4.7.2 as default
  compiler.
- gmp-static-mingw-4.1.tar

Please specify the correct procedure to configure gmp library.

Comment: This really isn't suited for SO because it doesn't involve any actual code, but a configuration problem.

Comment: I have no clue about gmp-static-mingw-4.1.tar contents but I would : copy gmp.h in your includes path (maybe in a gmp directory), and libgmp.a in your libraries path ?

Comment: @willll tried copying headers and libraries already but even the sample program couldn't run...

Comment: @ParasRautela : refine your question with your issue !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first put `gmp.h` into `..\Dev-Cpp\MinGW32\include` and both `libgmp.a` and `libgmp.la` into `..\Dev-Cpp\MinGW32\lib` directory, then create some project in DevCpp, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main(void)
{
    mpz_t x;

    mpz_init(x);
    mpz_set_str(x, "12345", 10);
    mpz_mul_ui(x, x, 2);

    gmp_printf("%Zd\n", x);

    mpz_clear(x);
    return 0;
}
```

After that go to Project Options -> Parameters and click Add Library of Object:

[image]

From the list select libgmp.a file (your static library) and click Open:

[image]

Compile and run you project, you will see some note about Makefile update, simply confirm.
[image]

Note that GMP 4.1 is now rather old, consider latest version and/or manual compilation for best possible performance on your configuration.